# Gmail - sent emails are staying in Inbox

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I have Gmail enabled with the send button "Send and Archive", but when I reply to an email, the message still stays in my Inbox.

I'm thinking that it could be one of my filters, as I have some filters that categorize messages as "Primary" (so that they don't end up in other categories like Promotions or Updates).

But nothing is standing out, I even tried removing the part of the filter that assigns certain emails to the "Primary" category but that hasn't helped.

I can't figure out why they are staying in my Inbox view, as read-messages.  It's a lot of clutter.

Answer (score -1):

No. It's not because of the filter as you said .any mail you send and receive will be shown in inbox.Moreover you can only find the sent mails in the sent icon and drafts in outbox